# Getting the alert Insert '!=null' check while using the if statement in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**The code is as below:**

```
public class Click {
private WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void Tocheckdifferentclickfeatures()  throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\abhishek.gautam\\workspace\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/mumbai");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("wzrk-cancel")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar']/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar']/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).click();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sunburn Arena with Martin Garrix (Mumbai)"))).isDisplayed()
```

I am getting the error on this line:

[Getting the alert Insert '!=null' check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLXeJ.png)

Comment: Click on the image link "Getting the alert Insert '!=null' check" for more details

Comment: Try adding isDisplayed() inside the if()

Comment: Actually the _error_ is 'Type mismatch: cannot convert WebElement to boolean'; the suggested _fix_ is 'Insert !=null'. You have an extra close-paren which is terminating the if-expression _before_ the `.isDisplayed()`. Remove the extra close-paren so you have a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as follows:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sunburn Arena with Martin Garrix (Mumbai)")).isDisplayed()){
   //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hey it worked optimist_creeper, but can you explain what exactly you did here that the code worked ?

Comment: @AbhishekGautam it was your syntax error. You placed isDisplayed() method out of if condition.